# Cannot delete a folder in a library

Tags: 2010, document-library, folder, delete

I am replacing a colleague for the support of a SharePoint 2010 intranet.
I want to delete a folder in a library.

The folder to delete is special :

- I can see the folder in the intranet
- I cannot see the folder in SharePoint Manager 2010
- I can see the folder in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell

I have tried to delete the folder in the intranet but I have got an error : Access Denied.
I do not understand because I have got the Full Control permission level on the folder.

I have also tried to delete the folder in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.
I have got a SPFolder object representing the folder and then I have called the Delete method.
But the call of the Delete method failed :

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot remove file "Sorocaba". Error Code: 16389."
At line:1 char:15
+ $folder.Delete <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Can someone please explain me how to delete the folder ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to inspect uls logs.
Also, could be helpfull to rename (move command) folder. May be renaming operation will change smg in folder.

Comment: I have clicked "Manage Permissions" on the folder in the intranet but I have got an error with a correlation ID.
I have searched for the correlation ID in the log file via ULS viewer but no entry has been found.
I have tried to rename the folder by using the SPFolder.MoveTo method in PowerShell but I have got the following exception :

Exception calling "MoveTo" with "1" argument(s): "The URL '<Current Folder URL>' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web."